# Replacing character values from a data frame in R, based on another data frame

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, data-cleaning

I'm trying to replace a large amount of values in a data frame based on a "codebook" of values. I have two tibbles:

```
head(df)
# A tibble: 6 x 6
  responseid color  q1_first_choice q1_second_choice q1_third_choice 
       <dbl> <chr>  <chr>           <chr>            <chr>                     
1         34 red    q1_red_b        q1_red_a         Pomegranate     
2         35 blue   q1_blue_a       q1_blue_c        q1_blue_b       
3         36 green  Tangerine       q1_green_b       q1_green_a      
4         37 purple q1_purple_b     q1_purple_a      q1_purple_c     
5         38 red    q1_red_a        Watermelon       q1_red_c        
6         39 green  q1_green_a      q1_green_c       q1_green_b    

head(codes)
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  Code      Name     
  <chr>     <chr>    
1 q1_red_a  Apple    
2 q1_red_b  Raspberry
3 q1_red_c  Cherry   
4 q1_blue_a Banana   
5 q1_blue_b Orange   
6 q1_blue_c Pineapple
```

I'd like to replace the values in df, across a large number of columns, with the codes$Name values. There are too many values to type out within a command, so I want to reference the columns in codes.

I imagine the answer might be some kind of variation of case_when, recode, or chartr, but I can't seem to figure out how to specify this within those functions.

Comment: It would greatly help if you can provide a reprex. Simply type dput(data frame name) into your console, and paste the output.

Comment: I would assume that you have all the corresponding 'Code' in 'code' dataset that is present in the 'df'.  In the data showed with `head`, some values doesn't have a corresponding match in 'codes' dataset

Answer (score 1):

We can use `mutate_at` to loop over the columns that starts with 'q1' and do the replacement by passing a named vector created from the 'codes' dataset

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    mutate_at(vars(starts_with('q1')), ~  setNames(codes$Name, codes$Code)[.])
```

---

Or another option is to do a `left_join` after reshaping to 'long' format

```
library(tidyr)
df %>%
   pivot_longer(cols = -c(responseid, color)) %>% 
   left_join(codes, by = c('value' = 'Code')) %>%
   mutate(value = coalesce(Name, value)) %>% 
   select(-Name) %>% 
   pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value)
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
i1 <- startsWith(names(df), "q1")
v1 <- setNames(codes$Name, codes$Code)
df[i1] <- lapply(df[i1], function(x) v1[x])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take:

First, pivot the data set into a long form. This is especially useful if response choices are shared among each column.

Then, join the long dataset with your codebook to get the new names.

Finally, (optionally?) coalesce the two columns together to preserve response choices that don't appear in your codebook. I say optionally because this step is only needed if there are original response choices that don't appear in your codebook.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(
  ~responseid,   ~color,  ~q1_first_choice, ~q1_second_choice, ~q1_third_choice,
           34,    "red",        "q1_red_b",        "q1_red_a",    "Pomegranate",
           35,   "blue",       "q1_blue_a",       "q1_blue_c",      "q1_blue_b",
           36,  "green",       "Tangerine",      "q1_green_b",     "q1_green_a",
           37, "purple",     "q1_purple_b",     "q1_purple_a",    "q1_purple_c",
           38,    "red",        "q1_red_a",      "Watermelon",       "q1_red_c",
           39,  "green",      "q1_green_a",      "q1_green_c",     "q1_green_b"
)

codes <- tribble(
        ~Code,       ~Name,
   "q1_red_a",     "Apple",
   "q1_red_b", "Raspberry",
   "q1_red_c",    "Cherry",
  "q1_blue_a",    "Banana",
  "q1_blue_b",    "Orange",
  "q1_blue_c", "Pineapple"
)

df_long <- df %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = starts_with("q"),
    values_to = "Code"
  )
df_long
#> # A tibble: 18 x 4
#>    responseid color  name             Code       
#>         <dbl> <chr>  <chr>            <chr>      
#>  1         34 red    q1_first_choice  q1_red_b   
#>  2         34 red    q1_second_choice q1_red_a   
#>  3         34 red    q1_third_choice  Pomegranate
#>  4         35 blue   q1_first_choice  q1_blue_a  
#>  5         35 blue   q1_second_choice q1_blue_c  
#>  6         35 blue   q1_third_choice  q1_blue_b  
#>  7         36 green  q1_first_choice  Tangerine  
#>  8         36 green  q1_second_choice q1_green_b 
#>  9         36 green  q1_third_choice  q1_green_a 
#> 10         37 purple q1_first_choice  q1_purple_b
#> 11         37 purple q1_second_choice q1_purple_a
#> 12         37 purple q1_third_choice  q1_purple_c
#> 13         38 red    q1_first_choice  q1_red_a   
#> 14         38 red    q1_second_choice Watermelon 
#> 15         38 red    q1_third_choice  q1_red_c   
#> 16         39 green  q1_first_choice  q1_green_a 
#> 17         39 green  q1_second_choice q1_green_c 
#> 18         39 green  q1_third_choice  q1_green_b

df_out <- df_long %>%
  left_join(codes, by = "Code") %>%
  mutate(Code = coalesce(Name, Code)) %>%
  select(responseid, color, name, Code) %>%
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = "name",
    values_from = "Code"
  )
df_out
#> # A tibble: 6 x 5
#>   responseid color  q1_first_choice q1_second_choice q1_third_choice
#>        <dbl> <chr>  <chr>           <chr>            <chr>          
#> 1         34 red    Raspberry       Apple            Pomegranate    
#> 2         35 blue   Banana          Pineapple        Orange         
#> 3         36 green  Tangerine       q1_green_b       q1_green_a     
#> 4         37 purple q1_purple_b     q1_purple_a      q1_purple_c    
#> 5         38 red    Apple           Watermelon       Cherry         
#> 6         39 green  q1_green_a      q1_green_c       q1_green_b
```

<sup>Created on 2020-03-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

For more information on pivoting, take a look at the [Pivoting vignette](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/articles/pivot.html) in tidyr.